# Como hacer un like en PostgreSQL pasandole parámetros

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net

Estoy trabajando con C# y PostgreSQL
Este es la consulta que tengo pero no me trae nada.

```
public static IEnumerable<Articulo> SelectList(UniversalExtend filter)
    {
        using (var cn = new NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                 WHERE (IdArticulo IS NULL OR IdArticulo LIKE @IdArticulo)
                 AND (Descripcion IS NULL OR Descripcion LIKE @Descripcion)";

                //cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT idArticulo, descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                //WHERE ((IdArticulo IS NULL) OR (idarticulo LIKE '%' || @idarticulo || '%'))
                //AND ((Descripcion IS NULL) OR (descripcion LIKE '%' || @descripcion || '%'))";


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idarticulo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
                    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                    : $"%{filter.Id}%");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
                    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                    : $"%{filter.Descripcion}%");

                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idarticulo", string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
                //    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                //    : filter.Id);
                //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@descripcion", string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
                //    ? (object)DBNull.Value
                //    : filter.Descripcion);

                var _articulo = new List<Articulo>();   
                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())    
                    {
                        var a = new Articulo()
                        {
                            IdArticulo = Convert.ToString(reader["idarticulo"]),
                            Descripcion = Convert.ToString(reader["descripcion"])
                        };
                        _articulo.Add(a);
                    }
                }
                return _articulo.ToList();   
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La consulta debería ser (sin los `%`):

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                WHERE ((IdArticulo IS NULL) OR (IdArticulo LIKE @IdArticulo))
                AND ((Descripcion IS NULL) OR (Descripcion LIKE @Descripcion))";
```

Y luego, cuando le pasas los parámetros al objeto command, allí le agregas el `%` a la cadena que le asignas a cada parámetro:

- `@IdArticulo` => `$"%{idArticulo}%"`
- `@Descripcion` => `$"%{descripcion}%"`

#### Edición

> me da este error: `Parameter '@IdArticulo' must have its value set`

Esto se debe a que no estás empleando la condición `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` correctamente. Debido a que estás verificando si la cadena *junto con el `%`* está vacía o null, obviamente, nunca te devolverá `true`, porque siempre tendrá `"%%"` como mínimo. Esto resulta en que aun cuando el valor sí está a null, de todas maneras el código viene a parar en el `else`, lo que te da el error.

**Versión corregida:**

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@IdArticulo",
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : $"%{filter.Id}%");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@Descripcion",
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : $"%{filter.Descripcion}%");
```

Cabe mencionar que la [respuesta de @Angeldev](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/43110/18951) también debería funcionar correctamente. Aunque me parece un poco raro que en ciertos casos la condición en la consulta resulte en `IdArticulo LIKE '%' || null || '%'`. Pero es perfectamente válido para tu situación.

#### Edición 2

Además del problema con el `LIKE`, la consulta tiene otro problemita. Según tus comentarios, la intención es que solo se haga la búsqueda con `IdArticulo` y `Descripcion` si los valores para estos parámetros no está a `null`. Pero eso no es lo que la consulta está haciendo, porque las condiciones `IdArticulo IS NULL` y `Descripcion IS NULL` se están haciendo con los ***campos*** en la base de datos, cuando en realidad tu intención es de verificar si los ***parámetros*** están a `null`.

La consulta correcta de acuerdo a lo que buscas debe ser esta (nota que le agregué el `@` en frente a las condiciones `@xxx IS NULL`, y aproveché para quitar las paréntesis innecesarias):

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                     WHERE (@IdArticulo IS NULL OR IdArticulo LIKE @IdArticulo)
                AND (@Descripcion IS NULL OR Descripcion LIKE @Descripcion)";
```

#### Edición 3

Y si necesitas que la comparación ignore las diferencias de mayúsculas y minúsculas, en PostgreSQL puedes usar el operador `ILIKE` en vez de `LIKE`:

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                     WHERE (@IdArticulo IS NULL OR IdArticulo ILIKE @IdArticulo)
                AND (@Descripcion IS NULL OR Descripcion ILIKE @Descripcion)";
```

#### Edición 4

Ok, creo que esta es la buena.

El problema con mi *edición 2* de agregarle el `@` en frente de la condición `@idArticulo IS NULL`, aunque la idea es correcta, es que ahora el driver le cuesta determinar el tipo del parámetro cuando el valor del parámetro es null. En efecto, difícil determinar el tipo de la expresión `NULL IS NULL`.

> could not determine data type of parameter $1

Para resolver esto, debes modificar la sentencia `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` para especificar el tipo explícitamente. De todas maneras, aun si el problema no sucediera, siempre es una buena idea de especificar el tipo explícitamente por razones que no voy a mencionar aquí para no salirme de tema.

De modo que combinando todo lo ante dicho, el código quedaría así:

```
// Usando ILIKE para evitar el problema de las diferencias 
// de mayúscuas y minúsculas
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
             WHERE (@IdArticulo IS NULL OR IdArticulo ILIKE @IdArticulo)
             AND (@Descripcion IS NULL OR Descripcion ILIKE @Descripcion)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@IdArticulo",
    NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, // le agregué esto aquí
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Id)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : $"%{filter.Id}%");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(
    "@Descripcion",
    NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, // le agregué esto aquí
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Descripcion)
        ? (object)DBNull.Value
        : $"%{filter.Descripcion}%");
```

Comment: me da este error Parameter '@IdArticulo' must have its value set, modifique la pregunta completando todo el query

Comment: El error tenía que ver con el `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, bueno que lo agregastes a la pregunta. Nota aparte, no se me había ocurrido, pero lo que dice @Angeldev es correcto también, para que tengas mas de una opción.

Comment: El using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) el reader me viene null

Comment: ¿Seguro? eso es prácticamente imposible. Usualmente, el contrato es que, o te devuelve un reader o te lanza una excepción, pero nunca debería devolverte null. Eso está raro.

Comment: El problema me parece que es con la sintaxis por que la db no lo interpreta por eso no me entra al reader.

Comment: Un error de sintaxis te lanzaría una excepción también. Entonces, ¿qué es lo que sucede exactamente? ¿La instancia `reader` está a null de verdad? (muy improbable) ¿O es simplemente que no devuelve ningún registro, o sea que `reader.Read()` siempre devuelve `false`. Porque si se trata simplemente de que la consulta no devuelve ningún registro, valdría la pena verificar la consulta en un programa cliente como PgAdmin primero, para asegurarte de que los parámetros están correctos.

Comment: Asi es no me manda error, no trae ningun registro pero en la base de datos si hay lo que le pido

Comment: hmm, tengo una sospecha. ¿Me puedes explicar el propósito de las condiciones `IdArticulo IS NULL` y `Descripcion IS NULL`? ¿De verdad se trata de querer devolver registros que tengan esos campos a null en la base de datos (lo que hace ahora)? ¿O será mas bien que la intención es de ignorar el parámetro si este está a null (la consulta no hace eso ahora)?

Comment: Exactamente puedo hacer una busqueda por código o descripcion si le mando el codigo me trae el codigo y si le mando la decripcion me tae la descripcion

Comment: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «:»
LINE 2: ... ((idarticulo IS NULL) OR (idarticulo LIKE '%' || :idarticul...

Comment: Ok, agregué una edición. Para hacer lo que pides, las condiciones `xxx IS NULL` deben hacerse con los parámetros, no los campos en la tabla.

Comment: No es, no se pudo determinar el tipo del parámetro $1

Comment: Eso suena a que tu código ha ido evolucionando... ¿se parece el código a lo que propuse, o ha cambiado a otra cosa? Tal vez si agregas una edición a la pregunta para poner el código que estás probando ahora, así como el error completo + stack trace.

Comment: El problema es que ni haciendo un query en la base de datos me sale las coincidencias que son como 20 lo maximo que he logrado traer es una

Comment: Con este query funciona: SELECT * FROM tblarticulos WHERE LOWER(descripcion) LIKE LOWER('%camiseta%');

Comment: Bueno, eso ya se trata de un problema de datos, con lo que no podemos ayudarte a menos que nos compartas muestras de tus datos.  Pero si estás acostumbrado a SQL Server, donde todas las comparaciones de cadenas son *case insensitive* por defecto, PostgreSQL no funciona así por defecto.  Las diferencias de mayúsculas y minúsculas son significativas.

Comment: Actualice la pregunta como me lo pediste

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51466/discussion-between-sstan-and-pedro-avila).

Answer (score 2):

En postgres la concatenación es con ||, entonces la consulta debería quedar así :

```
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                WHERE ((IdArticulo IS NULL) OR (IdArticulo LIKE '%' || @IdArticulo || '%'))
                AND ((Descripcion IS NULL) OR (Descripcion LIKE '%' || @Descripcion || '%'))";
```

ademas el valor del parámetro debería ser de la siguiente forma:

@IdArticulo => '1'

@Descripcion => 'desc'

de tal manera que al final lo que se ejecuta en el servidor de BD es algo así:

```
SELECT IdArticulo, Descripcion FROM tblarticulos
                    WHERE ((IdArticulo IS NULL) OR (IdArticulo LIKE '%' || '1' || '%'))
                    AND ((Descripcion IS NULL) OR (Descripcion LIKE '%' || 'desc' || '%'))
```